# PHP implode array to simple string

Tags: php, arrays

i want want to parse html attribute with function. in my fnction implode do not work correctly and could not convert array to simple string.

for example my array Result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id='myLabel'
    [1] => class='myClass'
    [2] => style='width:100%;'
)
```

after imploding that i get this Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0='id='myLabel' class='myClass' style='width:100%;''
)
```

Result must be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "id='myLabel' class='myClass' style='width:100%;'"
)
```

My function :

```
    public function setAttribute( $attributs ){
        $html = [];
        foreach ( (array)$attributs as $key => $value) {
            $html[] = $key .'='. "'".$value."'";
        }
        return implode( $html, ' ');
    }
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.serialize.php does the job

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Actually `$key` holds `array index` value. That's y in your array preceding with `0`

Comment: Your tried seems to [correct](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MXG8St).You should not get `0` and `weird quotes` after implode.

Comment: [Your code works fine](https://eval.in/private/76e2ed428c46d8). Please post how you are calling `setAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [manual](http://www.php.net/implode), it is used this way: 
`string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )`
`$string = ('<space>', $array)`

On your code its the other way around: 
 `return implode( $html, ' ');`

[Sample code:](http://ideone.com/vYXFKJ)

```
$array = array(
    "id='myLabel'",
    "class='myClass'",
    "style='width:100%;'",
);

Output:
Array
(
    [0] => id='myLabel'
    [1] => class='myClass'
    [2] => style='width:100%;'
)

$result[0] = implode(' ', $array);
Output:
Array
(
    [0] => id='myLabel' class='myClass' style='width:100%;'
)
```